# Bug of gcc? Access control issue about friend function in template class

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, access-control, friend-function

I have a template class, and I define a friend function inside the class.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class template_class {
    T v;
    friend void foo(template_class t) {
        t.v = 1;    // (1)can access the private member because it's a friend
        cout << t.v << endl;
        template_class<int> t1;
        t1.v = 2;   // (2)accessible if instantiated with [T=int]
        cout << t1.v << endl;
        template_class<char> t2;
        t2.v = 'c'; // (3)should not be accessible too if instantiated with [T=int]
        cout << t2.v << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    template_class<int> t;  // (4)generate void foo(template_class<int> t)
    foo(t);
    return 0;
}
```

If my understanding is correct, (4) generate the function `void foo(template_class<int>)`, and make it the friend of `template_class<int>`, so it can access the private member of `template_class<int>` like (1) and (2) in above source. But (3) should not be OK too, it's not the friend of `template_class<char>`, only `void foo(template_class<char>)` will be the friend of `template_class<char>`.

**EDIT**
As @Constructor and @Chnossos said, The above source compiled OK with [gcc 4.8.1](http://rextester.com/MQJJ73138), but failed with [clang 3.4](http://rextester.com/HQK90244). So which one is correct? Is it just a bug of gcc? Does the standard has an explicit definition about this case?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "The friend relationship isn't shared." But why the function can access the private member of `template_class<int>` and `template_class<char>` at the same time?

Comment: Sorry didn't read your question exactly. Forget about my comment ...

Comment: Please edit your post into a runnable example.

Comment: @ooga means [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)

Comment: @ooga You mean code with includes and `main()`?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile with [clang 3.4](http://rextester.com/ZOFSF56549).

Comment: @songyuanyao Yes. And make sure it compiles before posting, or say that it won't compile and mention the errors.

Comment: It compiles fine with [gcc 4.8.1](http://rextester.com/BANZR89354) though.

Comment: @Chnossos Yes, but it [doesn't print](http://rextester.com/RGZT76785) the last number.

Comment: @Constructor Yes because it's a char initialized with 0, and printing a `'\0'` prints nothing.

Comment: @Chnossos Oh, of course, you are right. I'm so silly. :-)

Comment: @ooga I edited the post. It compiled OK with gcc.

Comment: @Constructor I don't care about the result of print out, so I don't pay attention to the print out of char with value 0. I care for why the source can be compiled, and where my understanding about friend function is wrong.

Comment: Your understanding may be right because your code doesn't compile with clang, as I noted above.

Comment: IIRC this is a g++ bug, maybe related to http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41437 ?

Comment: @Constructor Yes, clang gave the error as I expected. So which one is right? Gcc or Clang? Does the standard has an explicit definition about this...?

Comment: @dyp It seems a little different...Maybe gcc is wrong, I'm just not confirmed so much.

Comment: @songyuanyao There are several bugs related to access control issues in class/function templates in g++. Some of them might be fixed in more recent versions of g++, but I think it's clear that the behaviour in your case violates the C++ Standard: There's a function `foo` declared for each instantiation of `template_class`, and each of those functions is a friend of only the instantiation it has been declared in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dyp says in the comments, this is simply a GCC bug. Either [PR 41437](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41437) or one of the others that [PR 59002](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59002) links to.